# How to select a child of a sibling element

Tags: jquery, dom, css-selectors, children, siblings

What I'm trying now, is to have a Submit button that will set the choice and record the score and I guess I'm struggling with how to traverse the DOM.  I think I'm trying to select the child of a sibling.  And I'm not sure why my current code isn't working for that purpose.

```
<div class='section' id='s1'>
    <div class='center' id='center1'>
        <div class='question' id='q1'>
        </div>
        <div class='choices' id='choices1'>
            <p class='a'>Choice A</p>
            <p class='b'>Choice B</p>
            <p class='c'>Choice C</p>
            <p class='d'>Choice D</p>
        </div>

        <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='submit'>
        <p class='score'></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var score = 0;
$('.choices p').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.choices').find('p').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('.submit').click(function() {
    var choice = $(this).prev('.choices').children().find('selected');
    if (choice.hasClass('a')) {
        score += 1;
    }
    else if (choice.hasClass('b')) {
        score += 2;
    }

    $(this).prev('.choices').find('p').off('click');
    $('.score').text('Score is ' + score);
});
```

Comment: it seems ur missing out the '.' in the selector for `find('.selected')`.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that too, but when I changed to '.selected' it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not

```
$('.choices p').on('click', function() {
        $('.choices p.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('.submit').click(function() {
        var choice = $('.choices p.selected');
        if (choice.hasClass('a')) {
            score += 1;
        }
        else if (choice.hasClass('b')) {
            score += 2;
        }

        $('.choices p').off('click');
        $('.score').text('Score is ' + score);
 });
```

Comment: I'll try it now.  My only concern though is if it will work for multiple questions.  I plan to have multiple questions just like this one so I want the click event on the submit button to apply to each question separately.  So each time, I need to choose only the p with the class 'selected' for the question that user is currently on.

Comment: You could add context to the selectors via `$('.choices p.selected', '#choices1')`

Comment: Great that got me pointed in the right direction!  Thanks!  Here's how I have it working:  $(this).prev('.choices).find('p.selected')

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors. Give this a try maybe?

http://jsfiddle.net/tallrye/bqpg1a8L/

```
$('.choices p').on('click', function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('.submit').click(function() {
    var score = 0;
    var choice = $('.selected');
    if (choice.hasClass('a')) {
        score += 1;
    }
    else if (choice.hasClass('b')) {
        score += 2;
    }

    $(this).prev('.choices').find('p').off('click');
    $('.score').text('Score is ' + score);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Like the answer above this pointed me in the right direction.  If I could check both answers I would.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'd go with [tallrye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744743/tallrye) answer, but to avoid removing all the selected class in your page you might want to use

> .siblings().removeClass("selected")

so it will only remove the class selected inside your div.choices

```
<div class='choices' id='choices1'>
        <p class='a'>Choice A</p>
        <p class='b'>Choice B</p>
        <p class='c'>Choice C</p>
        <p class='d'>Choice D</p>
</div>
```

Here:

```
 $('.choices p').on('click', function() {      
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```